# Linear Algebra question help

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble doing the first part of this problem. That is, proving $\det M_B = \left|\det B\right|^{2n}.$ Can you please help? Thank you. I have attached a pic of the problem.[image]

Comment: What have you already tried? This is a question that what type of answer will be useful to you will very much depend on what you already know.

Comment: Also, hint: calculate the determinant of the linear operator $L_B:V\rightarrow V$ defined by $L_B(A) = BA$ first. Then use similar logic to calculate the determinate of $R_B:V\rightarrow V$ given by $R_B(A) = AB^*$, and use the fact that $M_B = R_BL_B$.

Answer (score 2):

Very naively, we can simply look at the matrix representation of $M_B$ in the standard basis of $V$ consisting of all the matrices $E^i_j$ with a single $1$ in the $(i,j)$ position and zeroes elsewhere. Then a computation shows that the matrix $C = BE^k_l B^*$ is given by $C^i_j = b^i_k \overline{b}^j_l$. This means that the entries of the matrix representing $M_B$ consists of all the expressions of the form $b^i_k \overline{b}^j_l$, as all the indices run over $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Or, in other words, that each fixed $(k,l)$ yields a block $n \times n$ matrix $(b^i_k \overline{b}^j_l)$ at the $(k,l)$ component of $M_B$. (The exact representation depends on the ordering you picked for the bases.) But this matrix is just the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $B \otimes \overline{B}$. And by the general formula for the determinant of such a tensor product we get $$\det(M_B) = \det(B \otimes \overline{B}) = (\det B)^n \det(\overline{B})^n = (\det B \overline{\det B})^n = |\det B|^{2n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First, consider the map $M_B^{(L)}(A) = BA$.  Verify that if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is a basis relative to which the matrix of $B$ is *upper-triangular*, then the matrix of the transformation is upper triangular relative to the basis $\{e_ie_j^T\}_{i,j = 1}^n$ taken in lexicographical order.

You might prefer to consider the Jordan form, rather than an arbitrary upper triangular form.

With that, define $M_B^{(R)}(A) = AB^*$.

Having considered the matrices of these transformations, conclude that $\det(M_B^{(L)}) = \det(B)^n$, $\det(M_B^{(R)}) = \det(B^*)^n$, and that $M_B = M_B^{(R)} \circ M_B^{(L)}$.